# How to truncate fraction using NSNumberFormatter

Tags: ios, nsnumberformatter

How can I format decimal values with next rules

```
0.12345    => 0.12
10.12345   => 10.12
100.12345  => 100.1
1000.12345 => 1,000
```

Please, notice that idea is to take the same space.
C style `printf` allows to do this using something `4.2%f` plus somehow thousands separator but I don't get how to reflect it in Cocoa.

**UPDATE**

If you didn't notice example says that `0.12345` transformed to `0.12` not to `0.1234`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `NSNumberFormatter` ignores `maximumFractionDigits` when significant mode enabled I created custom class

```
class TRNumberFormatter: NSNumberFormatter {

    override func stringFromNumber(number: NSNumber) -> String? {
        let digitsCount = "\(number.integerValue)".characters.count
        let value = self.Tround(number.doubleValue, precision: min(self.maximumIntegerDigits - digitsCount, self.maximumFractionDigits))
        return super.stringFromNumber(value)
    }

    func Tround(value: Double, precision: Int) -> Double {
        let divisor = pow(10.0, Double(precision))
        return round(value * divisor) / divisor
    }    
}
```

To use it just

```
var numberFormatter: NSNumberFormatter = TRNumberFormatter()
numberFormatter.usesGroupingSeparator = true
numberFormatter.maximumIntegerDigits = 4
numberFormatter.minimumIntegerDigits = 1
numberFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2
```

Results

```
print(numberFormatter.stringFromNumber(0.12345)) // Optional("0.12")
print(numberFormatter.stringFromNumber(10.12345)) // Optional("10.12")
print(numberFormatter.stringFromNumber(100.12345)) // Optional("100.1")
print(numberFormatter.stringFromNumber(1000.12345)) // Optional("1,000")
```

Answer (score 0):

this comes close:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSNumberFormatter *nf = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
        nf.usesSignificantDigits = YES;
        nf.maximumSignificantDigits = 4;
        nf.usesGroupingSeparator = YES;
        NSLog(@"%@", [nf stringFromNumber:@(10.23455)]);
    }
}
```

**BUT it disregards the maximum of 2 fraction digits the OP wants and setting `maximumFractionDigits=2` doesn't work**

seems to me we can't emulate this 4.2%f exactly... without subclassing the whole thing

Comment: The problem here if I put 0.123456 it returns 0.1234 instead of 0.12

Comment: @Moldaone Yeah because of `nf.maximumSignificantDigits = 4;` perhaps?

Comment: @Moldaone I did.  You want a variety of outputs.  You've been given an answer which should work fine.  And yet you still have problems.

Comment: @Moldaone I am sorry for what I wrote - don't see how to do it

Comment: @Droppy Stack was created exactly for that reason, man. Should work and works are different things.

Comment: @Moldaone So the property to use is `maximumFractionDigits`.  It can't be that difficult to experiment with and besides Googling for "nsnumberformatter 2 decimals" gets you to a duplicate.

Comment: @Droppy does he really just want before and after the comma? I totally understood something else :D